# February 2019 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2019 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: WOW. The irony that the Community bot bumped this to the top today of all days is incredible.

Comment: Community bot wants mods today lol XD

Comment: I'm guessing anyone self nominating at this point would get the internet equivalent of being booed off the stage.

Comment: @Myles This election ended in February; it's probably just a coincidence that it was automatically bumped to the front page today. (The title was originally just "2019 Community Moderator Election," but I added the month to it in the hopes of reducing the potential for confusion.)

Comment: @TannerSwett Wise edit, and definitely just a coincidence. Still pretty hilarious though!

Comment: @Myles so, the questionn is:  WHO WANTS TO BE THE OFFICIAL SPEAR-CATHER?

Comment: LOL This is SO ironic. Makes me wonder if it's actually coincidence...

Answer (score -1):

There is a link to nominate myself, but no visible capability to nominate someone else. Why is this?

Comment: All nominations are self-nominations.  If there's somebody you'd like to see stand for election, please encourage the person to nominate.  (If the person is active in chat, try there.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment which is an answer to my "answer" which was a question to a statement which was not a question! :)

Comment: I LOL'ed way harder than I should have with this last comment